# Cannot append to node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a the following html code in a table:

```
<td id="description">
    <input id="newdescripion" value="VOIP/DATA" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="removeinput">Remove</button>
</td>
```

When I click the button, I would like to empty the td and add the text which is stored in a cookie. The td empties fine but I am unable to append the text. The text is in the variable as it is visible in the alert. I have used the code below to try and achive this, the commented out code is what I have tried and doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', '#removeinput', function() {
    var hostname =  $('#hostname').text();
    //alert(hostname);
    var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    //alert(trid);
    var olddesc = Cookies.get(hostname+','+trid+',description');
    alert(olddesc);
    $(this).closest('td').empty(); <----- THIS WORKS
    $(this).closest('td').append(olddesc);
    // $(this).closest('tr').find('#description').text(olddesc);
    // $(this).closest('td').text(olddesc);
    // $('#'+trid+' td').each(function(){
    //     if($(this).attr('id') == 'description'){
    //         $(this).append(olddesc);
    //     }
    // })
    //$(document).find('#'+trid+' td#description').append(olddesc);
})
```

Can anyone please help me fix this or recommend a better way of doing it?

Comment: `$(this).closest('td').html(olddesc);`

Comment: thanks, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: As you might imagine "doesn not seem to work" is a mostly useless piece of information.

Comment: ok, it does not work, i am still getting the same as before.

Comment: You still haven't told us what you got before.

Comment: i did in my post. the td empties, but it is not then appended with the required text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).closest('td').append(olddesc);` runs *after* you've removed `this` from the `td`, therefore the `td` is no longer an ancestor of `this`. You do not need to empty the `td`; simply set its text to `olddesc` and it will be automagically emptied as part of the process of setting its text.

```
// (REMOVE THIS) $(this).closest('td').empty(); <----- THIS WORKS 
$(this).closest('td').text(olddesc);
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that if the text contains HTML tags, using `$.text()` will escape those and render them as text. If that is unwanted, `$.html()` might be the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.html()` to add your dynamic data to HTML tag `id`

```
 var olddesc = Cookies.get(hostname+','+trid+',description');
 alert(olddesc);

 // Create custom / dynamic HTML
 var temp = `<p>` + olddesc + `</p>`;

 $(this).closest('td').empty(); <----- THIS WORKS

 // Edit: Use ID of html tag
 $('#description').html(temp);
```

This shall work for you.

Comment: thanks for the reponse, but this does not seen to work either.

Comment: Try with id Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.html`

```js
    $(document).on('click', '#removeinput', function() {
        var hostname =  $('#hostname').text();
        var olddesc = "Cokkies return"; //Cookies.get(hostname+','+trid+',description');
        $(this).closest('td').html(olddesc); //<----- THIS WORKS
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="description">
        <input id="newdescripion" value="VOIP/DATA" type="text">
        <button type="button" id="removeinput">Remove</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```